# Importing csv with json value with psql COPY (problem with escaping)

Tags: json, postgresql, csv, psql

I am trying to import csv file to table in postgres using COPY command. I have problem that one column is of json data type. I tried to escape json data in csv using dollars ($$...$$) [docu_4.1.2.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS).
This is first line of csv:

```
3f382d8c-bd27-4092-bd9c-8b50e24df7ec;370038757|PRIMARY_RESIDENTIAL;$${"CustomerData": "{}", "PersonModule": "{}"}$$
```

This is command used for import:

```
 psql -c "COPY table(id, name, details) FROM '/path/table.csv' DELIMITER ';' ENCODING 'UTF-8' CSV;"
```

This is error I get:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "$" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: $...
COPY table, line 1, column details: "$${CustomerData: {}, PersonModule: {}}$$"
```

How should I escape/import json value using `COPY`? Should I give up and use something like `pg_loader` instead? Thank you

Comment: So the dollars are there because you added them in the export right? You don't need that. I export tables with JSON data without any special escaping and import them with no problems. Granted I don't specify it as CSV, I just export it to a text file with a delimiter. So just change the way you export it.

Comment: I want to import data exported from Cassandra db. But you gave me right idea to export some json from postgres to check correct syntax.

Comment: @404  `I export tables with JSON data without any special escaping and import them with no problems` You ;) For more complicated scenarios of valid JSON it fails ;(

Comment: @404 got there with success finally by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59985022/953553

Answer (score 0):

In case of failing with importing the JSON data please give a try to the following setup - this worked for me even for quite complicated data:

```
COPY "your_schema_name.yor_table_name" (your, column_names, here) 
FROM STDIN 
WITH CSV DELIMITER E'\t' QUOTE '\b' ESCAPE '\';
--here rows data
\.
```